# Rapidminer generate new examples from splitted attributes

Tags: rapidminer

I have some data where one Attribute contains information, that has to be seperated into new examples (rows).

That Attribute is called: 'Group' and a value looks like: 'A+B+C'

I managed to split that Attribute, now I got 3 Attributes:

'Group_1': 'A', 'Group_2': 'B', 'Group_3': 'C'

This group has another attribute, e.g. 'Value': '3'.
Now I want my example set to contain examples with the attributes Group and Value, instead of having a merged example.

My table looks like this:

[image: Example Set].

I can manually multiply my process and select a subset with each group, then name then to Group and merge them together, but this is a static solution and the number of Group_x is not fixed.

Is there a way I can automate that process depending on the count of group_x attributes?  (Using a Macro-Operator I can only count all attributes)

The ExampleSet should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Pivot` operator will do this. Here's an example - the `Subprocess` is to create the data to match your data. The only operators you will need are the `Pivot` to do the work and `Select Attributes` to choose the attributes for the final result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.0.002" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Subprocess (2)" width="90" x="179" y="187">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="179" y="85">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Value" value="3"/>
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="179" y="187">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Value" value="13"/>
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;D&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" width="90" x="179" y="289">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Value" value="11"/>
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;D&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;B&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" width="90" x="179" y="391">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Value" value="32"/>
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;Missing&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;Missing&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" width="90" x="179" y="493">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="Value" value="5"/>
              <parameter key="Group_1" value="&quot;A&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_2" value="&quot;C&quot;"/>
              <parameter key="Group_3" value="&quot;Missing&quot;"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="166" name="Append" width="90" x="514" y="85"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value" width="90" x="648" y="85">
            <parameter key="mode" value="nominal"/>
            <parameter key="nominal_value" value="Missing"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_id" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate ID" width="90" x="782" y="85"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 3"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 4"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 5"/>
          <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Declare Missing Value" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate ID" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate ID" from_port="example set output" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="de_pivot" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="De-Pivot (2)" width="90" x="313" y="187">
        <list key="attribute_name">
          <parameter key="Group" value="Group.*"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="index_attribute" value="Value1"/>
        <parameter key="create_nominal_index" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.0.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="447" y="187">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="Group|Value|id"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Subprocess (2)" from_port="out 1" to_op="De-Pivot (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="De-Pivot (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Chris, that works perfectly! Is there a way to only take specific attributes for de-pivoting(e.g. for 'Group_1' only take 'Value' attributes, and for 'Group_2' only take 'Id' attributes?)

Comment: It will be possible - it might be complicated. I suggest posting a new question with a worked data example (you could use the example I gave to generate data to make the question standalone)   by the way, my name is Andrew :)

Comment: I am so sorry Andrew! Thank you for your help. I got a few more Questions I am going to ask :). Btw. I managed to do that with a bunch of loops :D.